# How to set expressions in ng-model for dropdown list?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am working with Angular JS (1.6).
I have to make four identical dropdowns with similar values using a for loop in my template.
This I have done. But I need to set some value for ng-model so that I can fetch the selected value of each dropdown list in my controller. How can I achieve that?

Below is my template (HTML) code:

```
<div id="destionationSection" class="row destionationSection-xs">
    <div ng-repeat="i in getDestinations(numberOfDestinations) track by $index">
        <div>
            <label>Destination-{{$index+1}}</label>
            <select id="destination-{{$index+1}}" ng-model="">
                <option value="none">Please select</option>
                <option ng-repeat="destination in destinations" value="{{destination.name}}">{{destination.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
```

So can anyone help me like what can I set in ng-model of each list so that each list will have unique ng-model value?

Comment: `selectedDestinations[$index]`?

Answer (score 0):

`ngModel` saved as `$scope` in *angularjs* and when you use `$scope` in `ngRepeat`, they can't be as one `value`, for example in this sample we have `link.selector` in our html which is repeat, but `ngRepeat` has unique **index** for all of them so your `ngModel` will be unique too.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
  $scope.options = [
  {name: 'options a'},
  {name: 'options b'}
  ]
  $scope.links = [
     {title: "A"},
     {title: "B"}
 
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in getDestinations(numberOfDestinations) track by $index">
            {{i.title}}
            <select ng-model="i.selector" ng-options="destination as destination.name for option in destinations"></select>
            
            you select: {{i.selector}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: so you want me to create separate object for iteration? Because The list which I am displaying in my drpdown is being fetched from backend.

Comment: no matter the options comes from where 'manual or from api', and target "is how to use it" not from where

Comment: No I didnt understand that why you created one more object "link"?

Comment: It's just sample but however i change it as your question, `ng-model="i.selector"` refers to our object `i`, not exist but we create it on the view

Comment: and what is selector in i.selector?